# Deleting the appropriate image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

So I'm almost done with an app that is supposed to behave like a photo gallery. I'm running into a novice issue though trying to properly delete photos. So, I have 3 UIImageViews. The images are stored in an NSMutableArray and loaded from it on startup. They delete and save perfectly. But, if I were to delete the image in UIImageView #2, then close and relaunch the app, the image from UIImageView #3 slides into #2's spot. That's fine and everything, until I try and delete the image in #2's spot or anything above #2's.

I delete the photos based upon the name, so if I try and delete the photo in UIImageView #2, my code will search for Image2.png and delete it. But, now when I relaunch the app, UIImageView #3 is sitting in #2's spot, so when I try and delete UIImageView #3, it will not delete since its looking for Image2.png, which is no longer there. The file in its spot is named Image3.png. So, I'm somewhat at a loss and have no idea how to edit my code to get around this issue. Here is the current code that I'm working with, the culprit here is `NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image%i.png",view.tag]];`. (I've tagged each UIImageView and am deleting based upon that):

```
- (IBAction)deleteButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *deleteAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete"
                                                              message:@"Are you sure you want to delete this photo?"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [deleteAlertView show];

    int imageIndex = ((UIButton *)sender).tag;
    deleteAlertView.tag = imageIndex;
}

- (UIImageView *)viewForTag:(NSInteger)tag {
    UIImageView *found = nil;
    for (UIImageView *view in self.array) {
        if (tag == view.tag) {
            found = view;
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}

- (void)alertView: (UIAlertView *) alertView 
clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger) buttonIndex
{


    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {

        UIImageView *view = [self viewForTag:alertView.tag];
        if (view) {

            [self.array removeObject:view];

            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
            NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image%i.png",view.tag]];
            NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

            NSError *error;

            [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];

            if (error)
                NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);

        }
        ((UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:alertView.tag]).image =nil;
    }   
    [self.user setObject:self.array forKey:@"images"];
}
```

And here is my full .m file just for reference:
https://github.com/Joey502/Test-Thing/wiki/.m-Class-File

If anyone knows how to fix this issue that would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is create another `NSMutableArray`, call it `fileNamesArray` that stores the filenames associated with each (in the same order) `UIImageView`s stored in your `self.array`.

When launching the app, you should store each filename (`NSString`s) in `self.fileNamesArray` at the same time you add the `UIImageView`s to `self.array`. Then, in your delete function, when you remove the `UIImageView` object from `self.array` and delete it from the directory, you should also remove the filename from `self.fileNamesArray`. So once the objects have been removed from both arrays, they will all shift by the same amount and each file name will correspond to the right image view.

Just to add to that: When deleting the images, you should use the `tag` of the `sender` to retrieve the filename from your `self.fileNamesArray` which you would then use to delete the physical file, whereafter you would remove it from the array (along with the image view). Here's an example of what your delete function should be like:

```
if (view) {
    [self.array removeObject:view]; //or you could do [self.array removeObjectAtIndex:alertView.tag];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self.fileNamesArray objectAtIndex:alertView.tag]];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSError *error;

    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];

    if (error)
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);

    [self.fileNamesArray removeObjectAtIndex: alertView.tag];
}
```

**Updated to address issues raised in comments:**

1. In your `applicationDidEnterBackground` method, you're adding all image views into `self.array` again. What if the array isn't empty? Then you're just adding items that aren't needed. The only things you need in this method are the last two lines.
2. In your `viewDidLoad` method, you're supposed to be adding the `fileName` string to `self.fileNamesArray`, but you've added the `imageView`. Remove all the lines that add the image view to this array and after `UIImage *loadedImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];` add this line `[self.fileNamesArray addObject:fileName];`
3. In your delete function, this line is missing two brackets: `NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self.fileNamesArray objectAtIndex:alertView.tag;`. It should be `NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self.fileNamesArray objectAtIndex:alertView.tag]];`. I'm wondering if this is why your whole directory is being deleted.
4. Don't forget that when you add images with the image picker, you should also add the filenames to the `fileNamesArray` in your picker delegate method (in the correct order).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried all the steps above but it ended up deleting my entire documents folder instead of just the picture, lol never seen that happen before.

Comment: Do you know why that could have happened?

Comment: Maybe place `NSLog(@"deleting file %@",[self.fileNamesArray objectAtIndex:alertView.tag]);` before deleting. It may be that your array hasn't been set up/updated correctly.

Comment: Ah okay thanks. I added that NSLog at the top of my alertView method, just before my if statement. The output was "deleting file (null)". Thats very strange, the images saved just fine.

Comment: Yes, so this means that you're not populating your array correctly. Make sure that whenever an image is removed, added, or when the application is loaded that all arrays are updated accordingly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that both of the arrays are being updated in accordance with each add/delete. I posted my entire file right here: https://github.com/Joey502/Test-Thing/wiki/.m-Class-File It all looks okay to me, but it probably isn't somehow. By the way, the bounty expires in 24 hours so I'll give it to you before then even though I haven't solved it yet, thanks for your help.

Comment: Cool thanks again. So, I deleted everything except the last two lines in appDidEnterBackground. I also deleted every instance of [self.fileNamesArray addObject:imageViewX]; in viewDidLoad, and I also added in [self.fileNamesArray addObject:fileName];. But, when I try to delete the image, it still deletes the entire Documents folder. I updated the .m file on github with my current code. Thanks again for your time and help.

Comment: Check edited answer. What are you logs outputting when you delete?

Comment: Thanks, I just fixed the brackets issue in my delete function, and added `[self.fileNamesArray addObject:imageViewX];` in each of my if statements in my imagePickerController method (I'm updating the github file with each change I make). The relevant output from the logs after hitting delete are: "deleting file (null)", "User Clicked Yes. Deleting index 2 of 3", and "After deleting item, array count  = 2". It looks like self.fileNamesArray is still empty, which is strange because I've added the file names to that array in each place that I add them into self.array.

Comment: At the end of your `viewDidLoad` method insert `NSLog(@"fileNamesArray has %d items",self.fileNamesArray.count);`. You need to try and locate the source of the problem, using `NSLogs` is a good start.

Comment: I saved 3 pictures, then ran the app again. The NSLog in `viewDidLoad` stated "fileNamesArray has 0 items". Very strange, it looks like I'm adding them to self.fileNamesArray in every place that I add them to self.array.

Comment: You'll need to check what the value of `fileName` is in your `viewDidLoad` method (NSLog), and check the number of items in `fileNamesArray` after each item is added. Look through your code for any reference to this array and make sure it is not emptying it.

Answer (score 1):

Check your use of self.array.  Sometimes you are using it to store/retrieve UIImageView's, other places you are storing/retrieving the images from the image views.

If you are trying to use self.array for two different purposes, then you either need to release and allocate a new one when switching purposes, or remove all the current contents before switching to the other purpose.